# TFS Token Authentication failing

Tags: git, powershell, http, tfs, azure-devops

My authentication with token (and password) is failing for the local TFS. It uses a proxy and has no internet connection. I should use the credentials from my Windows account. Also, I should use a personal access token, that I generated on the TFS page.

I am using it in the same format Microsoft specifies. 
"http://"MYUSERNAME":"MYPERSONALACCESSTOKEN"@"MYSERVERNAME":8080/tfs/main/Project/_git/Repository"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats

Cloning mirror using $url of a VSTS account. (which is fine using PAT from VSTS account)

```
git clone --mirror $url
```

Then git remote set url for future pushes. This url from a TFS local account.

```
$url2 = ("http://{0}@teamfoundation:8080/tfs/main/ProjectZero/_git/RepositoryAlpha/" -f $gitcred)

git remote set-url --push origin $url2
```

Then when pushing to the local TFS I get an error (not working using PAT generated on local TFS account)

```
git push --mirror
```

> fatal: Authentication failed for
>   'http://pt4005:pperkmngnanqrtqghjkrqwgoqrwwkykb4lezjqrrqwr@teamfoundation:8080/tfs/main/ProjectZero/_git/RepositoryAlpha/'

I can authenticate manually by just filling with login and password without using the token, when a window pops up when I push, but trying to use the token gives me that error.

Does anyone know what to do?

My credentials are stored in a string like this:

```
$gitcred = ("{0}:{1}" -f  [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($username),$token)
```

Comment: Did your TFS token only not work with GIT command, have you tired with some other thing such as Rest API? Will this authenticate correctly?

Comment: Any update on this issue Kevin?

Comment: Hey. Apparently using only the token without the username fixed the issue. It seems that for local TFS, the authentication is done entirely by the token. On the other hand, VSTS accepts the credentials as I posted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication for local TFS is different than VSTS. Use only the token, without the username on the calls.

Answer (score 0):

Use only the token without the username on the calls works from windows machine not working from linux machine